# Syntax error with exec call to an object in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, syntax-error

I really don't understand what causes the problem, could someone point it out for me please?

```
with shelve.open(obj_path) as obj:
    for as_num in obj['as_number_list']:  # ignore warning, obj['as_number_list'] is a list
        temp = charge_as(obj['as_' + str(as_num)])  # temp is an object
        as_test = temp  # doing like this is ok
        print(type(as_test))
        exec("as_{}_obj = {}".format(as_num, temp))  # **error here**
```

And it gives syntax error like this:

```
<class 'instruments.AS'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 45, in <module>
    exec("as_{}_obj = {}".format(as_num, temp))
  File "<string>", line 1
    as_1_obj = <instruments.AS object at 0x000002A86732E290>
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried

```
exec("as_{}_obj = {}".format(as_num, temp.__dict__))
```

no error is shown but now as_{}_obj is of class 'dict' instead of class 'instruments.AS'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line 45:
exec("as_{}_obj = temp".format(as_num))